# set common DATA DIRECTORY for all partitions in a table

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I'm trying to create a partitioned table on another drive with `DATA DIRECTORY`:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/stats_tables/test/db/mysql/';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> \! ls /stats_tables/test/db/mysql/db_test/
t1.ibd
mysql> drop table t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

So we see that an unpartitioned table is created successfully on the drive. Now let's try the same thing with a partitioned table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/stats_tables/test/db/mysql/' PARTITION BY HASH ( c1 ) PARTITIONS 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

mysql> \! ls /stats_tables/test/db/mysql/db_test/
mysql> \! ls /defa_storage/test/db/mysql/db_test/t1* | xargs -n1 basename
t1.frm
t1.par
t1#P#p0.ibd
t1#P#p1.ibd
t1#P#p2.ibd
t1#P#p3.ibd
t1#P#p4.ibd
t1#P#p5.ibd
t1#P#p6.ibd
t1#P#p7.ibd
t1#P#p8.ibd
t1#P#p9.ibd
```

We see that in this case it's created under the regular data directory.
This has perfect explanation in the [MySQL 5.5 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html):

> The DATA DIRECTORY and INDEX DIRECTORY options have no effect when defining partitions for tables using the InnoDB storage engine.

Although I use version 5.6 and there's no such a restriction mentioned in [its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Anyway, is there a way to set a common `DATA DIRECTORY` for all my `BY HASH` partitions?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I've found out I can actually control the created partitions in this manner:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
PARTITION BY HASH( ... )
(
    PARTITION p0 DATA DIRECTORY = '/another/directory',
    PARTITION p1 DATA DIRECTORY = '/another/directory', 
    PARTITION p2 DATA DIRECTORY = '/another/directory', 
    PARTITION p3 DATA DIRECTORY = '/another/directory', 
    ...
);
```

The last part can be easily generated by any scripting language, say, Python:

```
max_partitions = 100
for i in range(0, max_partitions):
  print("PARTITION p" + str(i) + " DATA DIRECTORY = '/another/directory',")
```